# set unique index's on a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the current dataframe and I want to set the index to `Id` and `GroupNumber` and have them as a unique value in the Index.  However, when I set the index the last index still gets duplicated (GroupNumber in my case).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Id':['A','A','A','A','A'],
'GroupNumber': [5,5,5,5,5],
'Name': ['John','Paul','George','Anthony','David'],
'Weight':['Average','Below Average','Above Average','Average','Above Average'],
'Height':['Tall','Short','Average','Tall','Average']})
```

```
df = df.set_index(['Id','GroupNumber'])
```

Desired Output:

[image]

Comment: All values in GroupNumber are the same

Comment: @DaniMesejo That is intended, should I be approaching this differently?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I have my desired output shown above

Comment: I see, the A are also duplicated on the index, you can see it by doing print(df.index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
df = df.set_index(['Id','GroupNumber'], append=True).reorder_levels([1,2,0])
```

Output:

```
                     Name         Weight   Height
Id GroupNumber                                   
A  5           0     John        Average     Tall
               1     Paul  Below Average    Short
               2   George  Above Average  Average
               3  Anthony        Average     Tall
               4    David  Above Average  Average
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to forget about the index or use `reset_index()` just before my code and modify the values in your dataframe prior to writing to excel:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Id':['A','A','A','A','A'],
'GroupNumber': [5,5,5,5,5],
'Name': ['John','Paul','George','Anthony','David'],
'Weight':['Average','Below Average','Above Average','Average','Above Average'],
'Height':['Tall','Short','Average','Tall','Average']})

df.loc[df.duplicated(['Id','GroupNumber']),['Id','GroupNumber']] = ''
df.to_excel('file.xlsx', index=False)
```

[image]

OR `to_csv`:

```
df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The first index will remove the duplicated , the 2nd lvl will not remove , if you do like it to be removed

```
df.assign(blank=['']*df.shape[1]).set_index(['Id','GroupNumber','blank'])
                         Name         Weight   Height
Id GroupNumber blank                                 
A  5                     John        Average     Tall
                         Paul  Below Average    Short
                       George  Above Average  Average
                      Anthony        Average     Tall
                        David  Above Average  Average
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you understand what an index is. Each row of your data needs to have a non-null value for its index. What you are trying to do is not possible.

if you don't mind having the name be the index you could do it this way

```
df = df.set_index(['Id','GroupNumber','Name'])
```

Comment: Are you saying that Index's have to be unique?

Comment: no i'm saying it can't be nothing, you are suggesting to create rows with literally no index